# $f(x-y) = f(x)f(y)$ defined from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$. find $f(3)$

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

The solution is given as if $x=0,$ then $f(0) \ge 0$
therefore $f(0) = 1$
and $f(3) = 1$

How?

Comment: Take $x=y=0$ to see that $f(0)=\left (f(0)\right)^2\implies f(0)=1$ (since $f(0)=0$ is excluded).  Then take $x=y=3$.

Comment: Putting $x=y$ we see that $\{f(x)\} ^{2}=f(0)$ is a constant and since $f$ is non-negative $f(x) $ is also a constant. Thus $f(x) =f(0)=1$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Because for $y=0$ we obtain $f(x)=f(x)f(0)$,
which gives $f(x)=0$ and $f(3)=0$ or
$f(0)=1$.

But for  $x=y$ we obtain
$$f(x)^2=f(0)=1$$ and since $f(x)\geq0$, we obtain $f(x)=1$ and $f(3)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Putting $x=y=0$ we get $f(0)=f(0-0)=f(0)f(0)$. Then either $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$.

If $f(0)=0$ then $f(x)=f(x-0)=f(x)f(0)=0$ for all $x$.

Otherwise let $f(0)=1$. Then $f(-y)=f(0-y)=f(y)$ for all $y$. Also then $1=f(0)=f(y-y)=f(y)f(-y)=f^2(y)$ for all $y$. Since $f(y)\ge 0$ for all $y$, hence $f(y)$=1 for all $y$.